# USB controlled relay

Tags: usb, relay

I have [this smart plug](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/gp/product/B07PPZS351/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) that allows for a separate ON/OF control of the USB ports. The idea is to use this USB switch to switch another device (230 V/ 500 mA).

For a good price I found [these relay modules](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/AZDelivery-1-Relay-KF-301-Module-Parent/dp/B07FNGCSZQ/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=5v%20relais&qid=1605429176&sr=8-4) on Amazon that are meant for Arduino.

My problem: the relay module has 5V input, I guess pins GND and VCC but also a Signal pin. What do I connect to the signal pin from my USB plug?

Thank you for your time.

[image: relay module]

[image: Connection, I guess to some controller]

Comment: The relays (or solid-state relays) are already in those "smart plugs" and can switch 16 A. Why do you want external ones?

Comment: My English lets me down today, so I meant: What USB pin do I connect to the Signal pin on the relay module?

Comment: @Transistor I already use the 16A Plug to control one device, I need the USB to control another device and because of space (and budget) limitations, I can't add another plug.

Comment: Then the smart relay is not relevant to your question. You are just asking how to switch on a relay module with a 5 V signal. Maybe you should edit your question.

Comment: @ Transistor As you can see, I'm new here, so I hope I didn't break any rules as I articulated my problem, but I tried to explain what I don't get: what USB pin to what relay module pin. I added the devices to make it more clear, therefore I think it is fairly relevant and if you don't mind I will let the question as it is for now.
Now to get back to business: what do I connect to the signal pin on the relay module, please?

Comment: You read the manual and connect the input so that the relay is on when powered.

Comment: You connect the pin to whatever it is that is going to control the relay - a microcontroller, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the switchable USB power outlets as controls then you simply power the module from the USB +5 V and GND lines and tie the relay control input to +5 V.

> My concern was that if I tie the USB +5V to both the VCC and IN pin on the relay module there is a short that would fry the circuit or the USB on my plug.

No. It is designed to be driven by a logic signal that switches from 0 V to 5 V. Connecting directly to +5 V does the same thing.

> Alternatively, could that work if I connect the USB DATA + to the signal input (IN) on the relay module?

No. DATA+ is a signal line, but not a logic signal and, most likely, it isn't even connected in the USB socket.

Comment: You mean I should tie the USB +5V twice on the relay module? Once for power and once for signal?

Comment: Yes. I'm not going to look at the Amazon ad because it is unlikely that there will be a datasheet. ("No datasheet? No sale!") Most of them have a jumper to select how the logic works and you won't damage the module by trying connecting to  +5 or GND.

Comment: I updated the post with product images so that the Amazon product links won't be needed. As you see there is no jumper. My concern was that if I tie the USB +5V to both the VCC and IN pin on the relay module there is a short that would fry the circuit or the USB on my plug. Alternatively, could that work if I connect the USB DATA + to the signal input (IN) on the relay module?

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be aware of what is low level trigger and what is high level trigger.

Does this relay will be closed on HIGH or LOW? First you answer this.

After that you said it is a 5 V relay. So yes you can feed it with 5 v directly to make it closed.

If it triggers with ground, then you should connect the signal pin to ground to make the relay closed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I am aware of how the relay functions. If you look at the pic above you can see that the relay can be used both normally closed and open. The only concern was the 5V trigger signal, which Transistor kindly answered.